# Service Status orders vs sellers and products

Tags: amazon-mws

Does any one know if the service status in the orders part of the API is the same as the ones in the Sellers and Products?

Or does it return the status of each section? If this were the case would the Feeds API not also have a service status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same, I ran into all sorts of API issues as I didn't realize that the Feeds API and the Reports API is the same API for instance, and on more then just service status, so keep an  eye on that.

Comment: How did you convert datetime to the ISO date Amazon requires?

Comment: I use UTC for everything I do with Amazon - makes it easier as thats how they refer to everything within the API. For generating reports I use the following :  utcStart = new DateTime(curYear, lastMonth, yesterday, sHour, sMinute, sSecond);
                utcEnd = new DateTime(curYear, curMonth, curDay, eHour, eMinute, eSecond); Just set your curYear, curMonth variables to the appropriate values.

Comment: If you want to convert the utcStart to Pacific Time (which amazon also uses ) I use the following method:                                       public static DateTime UtcToPacific(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"));
        }

Comment: I have this atm `request.CreatedAfter = Convert.ToDateTime(dc.Settings.SingleOrDefault().lastOrdersRetrieved);` I think this is causing me issues as i am storing as a DateTime.Now

Comment: If you want to create a new question, I'll post some more info on orders and createdAfter times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563047/listing-orders-and-passing-iso-8601-date-to-amazon-mws

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be the same thing. I can find no info to show otherwise. Oh well.